# Элементы массива JS

Tags: javascript

Как вывести диапазон идущих по порядку элементов массива?

```
 Чтобы из такого:      35,3,6,9,11,12,13,14,15,39,9,21,25,26,27
 На выходе было такое: 35,3,6,9,11-15,39,9,21,25-27
```

Comment: хоть какие то наработки то у вас есть? цикл для начала напишите что ли. проверку текущего значения с предыдущим и т.д.

Comment: Да, есть. Я циклом вытягиваю непрерывные последовательности чисел и пушу их в отдельный массив. Но вот потом как оставить только начальное и последнее значение не понимаю как сделать(

Comment: `arr[0]+"-"+arr[arr.length-1]`

Comment: У меня на выходе получается такой массив 
11,12,13,14,15,25,26,27
как мне вытянуть только 11-15 и 25-27 ?

Comment: @MarinaDolganova добавьте код в вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пушьте в массив строки

```js
var data = [35, 3, 6, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 39, 9, 21, 25, 26, 27];
var res = [];
var start = 0;
var stop = start;
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i] == data[i - 1] + 1)
    stop = i;
  else {
    if (start == stop)
      res.push(data[start]);
    else
      res.push(data[start] + '-' + data[stop]);
    start = i;
    stop = start;
  }
}

if (start == stop)
  res.push(data[start]);
else
  res.push(data[start] + '-' + data[stop]);
  
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо, поняла!

Comment: @MarinaDolganova Может быть, для последующего парсинга, проще пушить объекты вида `{from: 5, to: 10}`, а не строки

Answer (score 1):

вариант...

```js
function fn(f) {
  var c = void 0;
  return f.reduce(function(e, d, a, b) {
    a = d + 1 == b[++a];
    b = void 0 === c;
    a && b ? c = d : a || b ? !a && b && e.push(d) : (e.push(c + "-" + d), c = void 0);
    return e;
  }, []);
};
var data = [35, 3, 6, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 39, 9, 21, 25, 26, 27];
console.log(fn(data))
```